# How to convert UNIX epoch days to DATE in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have some values which correspond to the number of days since Epoch and want to store them in DATE column in Snowflake.

Example:
33057

Corresponds to Sunday, July 4, 2060

Would be really helpful if someone can point me to the correct Snowflake documentation(if available out of the box) for such

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
select dateadd(day, <your number> - 33057, '2060-07-04')
```

So, for the specific conversion of "33057", this would be:

```
select dateadd(day, 33057 - 33057, '2060-07-04')
```

But it should work for any integer.

Comment: Thanks since this is from epoch time I tested this works well for `select dateadd(day, 33057, '1970-01-01')`

Comment: @user3255021 . . . True, but there is no need to determine the epoch start, because your question has enough information.  Wikipedia has a rather amusing list of dates that are considered the start of "epochs":  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing).

Answer (score 3):

[TO_TIMESTAMP_x](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html)(numeric_expr) is what your looking for. And if you only want the date part I would then truncate via `::DATE`

> *numeric_expr*
>   A number of seconds (if scale = 0 or is absent) or fractions of a second (e.g. milliseconds or nanoseconds) since the start of the Unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC). If a non-integer decimal expression is input, the scale of the result is inherited.

if you have milliseconds you can use the `TO_TIMESTAMP_x(numeric_expr, scale)` form

```
select to_timestamp(12334567) as t_from_s
  ,to_timestamp(12334567000, 3) as t_from_ms;
```

gives

```
T_FROM_S                   T_FROM_MS
1970-05-23 18:16:07.000    1970-05-23 18:16:07.000
```

We use the `_NTZ` variant for all our usages, as we have all data in UTC from the servers.

Comment: As I put in my question the numeric_expr I have is number of days since epoch and TO_TIMESTAMP I could not find a scale to convert that to timestamp

Comment: ah, it seems I did not read well enough, as I saw epoch, and "everyone" knows UNIX epoch is seconds... where-as you just have days since '1970-01-01'